# Increase Product Price by specific amount for all Products - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product, database, price, magento-1.9.3.4

I am running Magento version 1.9.3.4 with PHP 5.6.40 for my store and it has around 5000 products. So I need to increase the product price by Rs.1000 for all products. I just added below custom code in **updateprice.php** file in my Root and  executed it by **mysite.com/updateprice.php** but unfortunately its not working.

Here is my code :

```
<?php

require_once('../app/Mage.php');
Mage::app('default');

$priceToAdd = 1000;

$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$write->query("
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_decimal val
SET  val.value = (val.value + $priceToAdd)
WHERE  val.attribute_id = (
SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute eav
WHERE eav.entity_type_id = 4
AND eav.attribute_code = 'price'
)
");
```

Can anyone know how to fix this?

**Note :** Then Price change should applicable for both Price & Special price. For example If the products have both price & special price then the price 1000 should increased to both. If the products only have the price then it should updated that price alone.

Comment: use data profile to for this

Answer (score 5):

Try below code:

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
require_once ( "app/Mage.php" );
Mage::app();
umask(0);
$priceToAdd = 1000;
$_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
if ($_products->count()) {
    foreach ($_products as $_product) {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
        $updater = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action');
        $updater->updateAttributes(array($product->getId()), array('price' => ($product->getPrice() + $priceToAdd)), 0);

        if ($product->getSpecialPrice() != '') {
            $updater->updateAttributes(array($product->getId()), array('special_price' => ($product->getSpecialPrice() + $priceToAdd)), 0);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update: To update prices using percentage amount.**

Change:

```
$updater->updateAttributes(array($product->getId()), array('price' => ($product->getPrice() + $priceToAdd)), 0);
```

To:

```
$updater->updateAttributes(array($product->getId()), array('price' => ($product->getPrice() + (($product->getPrice() * $percentage)/100))), 0);
```

and

Change:

```
$updater->updateAttributes(array($product->getId()), array('special_price' => ($product->getSpecialPrice() + $priceToAdd)), 0);
```

To:

```
$updater->updateAttributes(array($product->getId()), array('special_price' => ($product->getSpecialPrice() + (($product->getSpecialPrice() * $percentage)/100))), 0);
```

Comment: thanks I will try this. Can you please let me know how to **increase & decrease products by Percentage & Specific amount** with above code?

Comment: For a specific amount, I have already answered. For the percentage change, please check my update.

Comment: Thanks. You have mentioned Specific Amount & Percentage **Increase**. Also please let me know the same for **Decrease**

Comment: For **Decrease**, you can use minus sign (-) in place of the plus sign (+).

Comment: For Percentage Decrease?

Comment: For percentage decrease also.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to check this & update here